# sql group by - curse and blessing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables for a meal calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE Meals (
    meal_id int,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredients (
    ingredient_id int,
    name text,
    minamount float,
    price float
);

CREATE TABLE Recipe (
    meal_id int,
    ingredient_id int,
    quantitiy float,
    ingredientName text
);
```

Now I like to find a meal by ingredient:

```
SELECT m.meal_id, 
                    m.name,
                    r.ingredientName
                    from meals m
                    join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
                    join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
                    where r.ingredientName = 'meat'
                    group by m.meal_id
```

Which give me a list like:

```
name, ingredientName
Lasagne, meat
Bolognese, meat
```

Also I like to find meal by price like:

```
SELECT m.meal_id, 
                    m.name,
                    SUM(i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity) as mealPrice
                    from meals m
                    join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
                    join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
                    GROUP BY m.meal_id, 
                             m.name
                    HAVING mealPrice > 5.0 AND mealPrice < 8.0
```

Which give me a list like:

```
name, mealPrice
Lasagne, 6.5
Bolognese, 7.8
```

Now let me build a query like

```
SELECT m.meal_id, 
                    m.name,
                    r.ingredientName,
                    SUM(i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity) as mealPrice
                    from meals m
                    join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
                    join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
                    where r.ingredientName = 'meat'
                    GROUP BY m.meal_id
                             r.ingredientName  
                    HAVING mealPrice > 5.0 AND mealPrice < 8.0
```

Which gives me a list like:

```
name, ingredientName, mealPrice
Lasagne, meat, 1.99
Bolognese, meat, 1.99
```

Because (i.price / i.minamount * r.quanitity) for this meal for meat is 1.99

Without "GROUP BY r.ingredientName" it returns only one values

```
name, ingredientName, mealPrice
Lasagne, meat, 6.5
```

But I need a list like:

```
name, ingredientName, mealPrice
Lasagne, meat, 6.5
Bolognese, meat, 7.8
```

Comment: You could take a little time to fix the create tables which are syntactically incorrect and your queries r.showname for example does not exist.

Comment: thanks a lot Salmon, r.showname is off course r.ingredientName, create table statement are simplefied for this post.. but I think the problem is clear, how do you solve it?

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: first move `r.ingredientName = 'meat'`  to `WHERE` OR better to `JOIN`

Comment: thanks a lot @bato3, I changed it - but How can I get my expected value

Comment: are you sure, that *Bolognese* cost between `5.0` and  `8.0`? (remove `HAVING`) AND add where is coma after `GROUP BY m.meal_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps add an EXISTS to only get the meals with 'meat' in the recipe.

```
SELECT 
 m.meal_id, m.name,
 SUM((i.price / i.minamount) * r.quantity) as mealPrice
FROM meals m
JOIN recipe r ON r.meal_id = m.meal_id
JOIN ingredients i ON i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM recipe r2
  WHERE r2.ingredientName = 'meat'
    AND r2.meal_id = m.meal_id
)
GROUP BY m.meal_id, m.name
HAVING mealPrice BETWEEN 5.01 AND 7.99
```

Comment: :) Btw, if you want to verify if the ingredients of the meal contain meat? Then if your MySql version has the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function , then you could play with that.

Comment: Also, I used a BETWEEN. That's just an alternative to the `mealPrice > 5.0 AND mealPrice < 8.0`. So it's perfectly fine to use your method of limiting on the meatPrice. But note that a BETWEEN includes the start and the end value.  So `where x between 1 and 3` is equivalent to `where x >=1 and x <= 3`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                SELECT m.meal_id, 
                m.name,
                r.ingredientName,
                SUM(i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity) as mealPrice
                from meals m
                join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
                join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
                where r.ingredientName = 'meat'
                GROUP BY m.meal_id, r.ingredientName  
                HAVING  mealPrice > 5.0 AND mealPrice < 8.0
```

Comment: I already tried it because bato3 said I should move `r.ingredientName = 'meat'` to `WHERE`